# Angular : Can't order array by ascending order

Tags: angular

First of all sorry for my bad English.
My website consume an asp.net core Api.
The method to recover datas is the following:

```
getData(): Observable<INavigation> {
let apiNavigation: string = environment.apiAddress + 'Navigation';
this.repository.getData(apiNavigation)
    .subscribe((response) => {this.navigations = response as INavigation[]});
return this.navigations.sort((a,b) => b.sequence - a.sequence) as INavigation[];
```

}

This method use a repository service who uses HttpClient get method.
I have result in the response and finally I try to order results by ascending order on sequence field but it doesn't.
Is there anyone who can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues with your code.

First of all, you need to sort the array within the `subscribe` callback, otherwise you end up sorting the array *before* it is set (the callback is async):

```
getData() {
    let apiNavigation: string = environment.apiAddress + 'Navigation';
    this.repository.getData(apiNavigation).subscribe(response => {
      this.navigations = response as INavigation[];
      this.navigations.sort(
         (a, b) => b.sequence - a.sequence
      )
    });
  }
```

Moreover, you declare `getData` return type as Observable, but you're trying to return a plain array instead. Since you're storing the sorted array as an instance member I guess `getData` might be `void`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I tried your solution but the array isn't sorted.

Comment: Can you add more details about how you're using the `navigations` property? Are you using it in a template? Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pw5pq1) where the sorting works as expected

Comment: Yes I use it like this : 
 <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse
  justify-content-start">
  <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <span *ngFor="let item of navigations">
    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">{{item.description}}</a>
   </span>
  </div>

Indeed your example works. But in my case the sort doesn't work.

Comment: You should share more code, possibly put together a minimal working example. The sorting should work as long as: (1) you're accessing the array _after_ it has been sorted and (2) your response data has a `sequence` property. Also note that you're applying sorting in descending order.

Comment: I compiled my solution again and it's seems to be ok. Items are ascending sorted. Thanks for your helpfull help!